# socket io address gives ffff value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

How do I get the address value(192.168.0.number) only, cause when I console the 'address' it gives me an additional value '::ffff:address'

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var usernames = {};
var numUsers = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var addedUser = false;
  var address = socket.handshake.address;

  console.log("New connection from " + address);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to. `:ffff:192.168.0.1` is a full valid address. Specifically it's an IPv6 address. You can ping it directly. If you have ssh access to it you can ssh to it directly. If you need to file a complaint to your ISP you should give that address, not 192.168.x.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address. I suppose the easiest way to extract the IPv4 portion would be to do something like:

```
// ...
var idx = address.lastIndexOf(':');
if (~idx && ~address.indexOf('.'))
  address = address.slice(idx + 1);
```

Comment: Actually it's best to not extract the IPv4 address at all because the full address is actually a valid address. The OP simply doesn't know about IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Well, assuming they are using it only for display purposes as in their original code, there is no harm.

Comment: yes, I'm using it for display purposes i need to hash it also, semi columns and periods need to be removed. thanks

Comment: isn't there a way to make it so that socket.io doesn't add that bit if it's not a valid IPv6?.. sorry i just realized how old this thread is but i can't really find a solution other than to have an old version of either node or socket.io... i just know that after i updated my node.js version it started doing this. n -stable few days ago. I think its like 10.53 or something